# Storing the most frequently accessed items in redis, at a per user level

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redis

I have the models User and Item. What would be the best way to store the list of 5 most frequently accessed items per user, in redis?

Answer (score 1):

Have a set containing all the users id

```
sadd users user1 users2 ...
```

For each user have a sorted set containing item and it's count:

```
ZINCRBY ACTION_COUNT_user1 1 item1
```

If you want to retrieve based on last accessed time do this:

```
zadd ACTION_COUNT_user1 1467816772 item1 (here 1467816772 is timestamp)
```

Now if you want to retrieve top 5:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE ACTION_COUNT_user1 0 4
```

Hope this helps